# multiprocessing to add a column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiprocessing

I try to add new columns in a huge pandas dataframe. I wrote a function to add the new columns and can now loop over the dataframe. This works, but since the dataframe is so big it takes quite a while. So I tried to use the `multiprocessing` module to speed up, but was not able to make it run.

Below is a MWE. I guess `pool.map()` cannot change the dataframe directly and I need to save the new columns first somewhere else. Note: In the "real" code I will add more than 100 new columns and those are also based on values in other dataframes (so I guess `apply` is not possible).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool


df = pd.DataFrame({"Value1" : [1,2,3], "Value2" : [9,8,7]})

def make_new_columns(i):
    df.loc[i, 'mean'] = np.mean([df.loc[i, 'Value1'], df.loc[i, 'Value2']])
    df.loc[i, 'sd'] = np.std([df.loc[i, 'Value1'], df.loc[i, 'Value2']])
    df.loc[i, 'cv'] = df.loc[i, 'mean'] / df.loc[i, 'sd']


# With a for loop it is working
# for i in range(len(df)):
#     make_new_columns(i)

# With multiprocessing it isn't 
pool = Pool()
pool.map(make_new_columns, range(len(df)))
```

Thanks for you input.

EDIT:

To give a bit more background. I have a data.frame containing tennis match data (Match_Table) which looks a bit like this:

Match_Table:

```
Date      Player_1     Player_2     Winner      Aces_1  Aces_2   [...]
----------------------------------------------------------------------
20200528  Thomas       Peter        Thomas      6       2
20200526  Peter        Michael      Peter       8       3
20200524  Donald       Bill         Bill        3       12
...
```

Now, I am interested into statistics of a specific matchup. So for example: "What was the winrate of e.g. Peter in the last 100 games?", "How many aces did he score on average?", "How many aces did his opponent score?", "How was his win rate against e.g. Bill in the last 100 games?", ...

I need this statistics also for different dates in the past (e.g. What was Peters win rate January 2018). Therefore, I make a second table with the required information (Statistic_Table):

Statistic_Table:

```
Date    Player1  Player2   
----------------------------------------------------------------------
202002  Thomas   Peter    
202002  Peter    Michael  
201905  Donald   Bill     
...
```

Then I wrote a function which filters the Match_Table and calculates all missing columns of Statistic_Table. I can now loop over each row, so it results in this:

```
Date    Player  Opponent  Winrate Winrate_vs avgAces [...]          
-------------------------------------------------------------
202002  Thomas  Peter     0.47    0.45       4.5     
202002  Peter   Michael   0.54    0.64       8.4           
201905  Donald  Bill      0.63    0.78       6.5     
...
```

Every thing works fine. But since for every cell in my quite large Statistic_Table, I have to subset another table and calculate statistics (not only mean or rates but also weighed averages, etc.), it takes several hours. This would be possible, since I need to create the table just once. But still, if I could split the workload on different cores it would be faster and also easier in the case I have to adjust some parameters.

I also looked in the possibility to use some `apply` method or optimize the code, but since I (hopefully) only need to generate the table, once I don't want to lose too much time on this. Thus, multiprocessing seemed an easy solution especially, since I have access to powerful computers.

Comment: With this way of building, you are in fact constructing you df one cell at a time (with the `.loc`), which is very likely where the speed issue is coming from. We would need more detail on your use case to see if it could be build one full column at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a better module for your use case than multiprocessing. Use Ray.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import ray

ray.init()

@ray.remote
class DataFrameActor:
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df.copy()

    def make_new_columns(self, i):
        self.df.loc[i, 'mean'] = np.mean([self.df.loc[i, 'Value1'], self.df.loc[i, 'Value2']])
        self.df.loc[i, 'sd'] = np.std([self.df.loc[i, 'Value1'], self.df.loc[i, 'Value2']])
        self.df.loc[i, 'cv'] = self.df.loc[i, 'mean'] / self.df.loc[i, 'sd']

    def to_df(self):
        return self.df

@ray.remote
def worker(_df_actor, value):
    _df_actor.make_new_columns.remote(i=value)

df = pd.DataFrame({"Value1" : [1,2,3], "Value2" : [9,8,7]})
df_actor = DataFrameActor.remote(df)

[worker.remote(df_actor, j) for j in range(len(df))]
print(ray.get(df_actor.to_df.remote()))
```

Comment: I will read in the `ray` module and try it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the functions in your MWE represents what you want to do in your real frame, you should work column-wise.

```py
df['mean'] = df[['Value1', 'Value2']].mean(axis=1)
df['sd'] = df[['Value1', 'Value2']].std(axis=1)
df['cv'] = df['mean'] / df['sd']
```

Below is timing code (where df is built with more rows and values are randomly drawn integers)

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool


n_rows = 2000

df = pd.DataFrame({"Value1" : np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=n_rows),  
                   "Value2" : np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=n_rows)})

# Function takes now df as input so no global variables is changed
def make_new_columns(df, i):
    df.loc[i, 'mean'] = np.mean([df.loc[i, 'Value1'], df.loc[i, 'Value2']])
    df.loc[i, 'sd'] = np.std([df.loc[i, 'Value1'], df.loc[i, 'Value2']])
    df.loc[i, 'cv'] = df.loc[i, 'mean'] / df.loc[i, 'sd']
    
    return df

#cellwise construction: 1.98s 
%%timeit
df_2 = df.copy()
# With a for loop it is working
for i in range(len(df_2)):
     make_new_columns(df_2, i)

# columnwise construction: 2.4**ms**
%%timeit
df_2= df.copy()
df_2['mean'] = df_2[['Value1', 'Value2']].mean(axis=1)
df_2['sd'] = df_2[['Value1', 'Value2']].std(axis=1)
df_2['cv'] = df_2['mean'] / df_2['sd']
```

Comment: Unfortunalty the MWE uses simplified functions as an illustration. Actually for each new cell, I am subsetting another dataframe and take the mean, weighted average or some other value of the subsetted dataframe.

Comment: Sounds like a (one-to-many) merge + some aggregation is what you are in fact doing. 
Do you think you could share a slightly bigger MWE?

Comment: I added a bit more explanation to the question. I started to work on a MWE but soon realized that it takes quite some effort. I hope and guess that the additional information is sufficient to explain my problem better. 
If you think there would be a more elegant approch, I could provide more information.